# Restrict dnsmasq to offer DHCP to VMs on localhost only?

Tags: dnsmasq

I need to set up dnsmasq to offer DHCP (and optionally DNS) to VMs running on the localhost only, and not to any other systems doing a DHCP Discover that are external to the box running dnsmasq. Do I just set the options:

```
interface=lo0
bind-interfaces
```

Or is there other config that is needed?

Answer (score 1):

Listening on the loopback interface will probably not work, because your virtual machines are not attached to the loopback interface (so `dnsmasq` will not see their DHCP requests).

You will need `dnsmasq` to listen on the interface to which your virtual machines are attached.  Typically, this will be a bridge interface.  Without seeing how your system is configured it's difficult to offer a more detailed answer.

If you are using `libvirt`, then by default (at least under RedHat-ish systems) you get a `dnsmasq` instance listening on `virbr0` that start up like this:

```
/sbin/dnsmasq --strict-order --local=// --domain-needed \
  --pid-file=/var/run/libvirt/network/default.pid \
  --conf-file= --except-interface lo --bind-dynamic --interface virbr0 \
  --dhcp-range 192.168.122.2,192.168.122.254 \
  --dhcp-leasefile=/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/default.leases \
  --dhcp-lease-max=253 --dhcp-no-override
```

Comment: The trouble with this is that the bridge will have the `eth0` int as a part of it (i.e. the network interface that connects the hypervisor to the network will be a part of the same bridge that the VMs are connected to...) I don't want the possibility of the hypervisor host running dnsmasq to provide DHCP to the network that the hypervisor host is connected to.

Comment: So don't bridge your VM instances to `eth0`.  Keep them on an internal private network and *route* them to the outside world instead of bridging.

Comment: this will not work for our design. But now I understand (at least I *think* I understand) that what I want is not possible if the hypervisor and the VMs are all on the same network.

Comment: You could configure `dnsmasq` to only respond to known MAC addresses (and then add explicit leases for each vm).